# MATLAB System Error: MATLAB has encountered an internal error and needs to close

Tags: matlab

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYvMB.jpg)

When I opened Matlab I encountered this problem. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

go to your `matlab` pref dir (in Linux its `~/.matlab/R2010b/` for `R2010b` version) backup this folder and remove `matlabpref.mat`

Comment: You can locate the prefdir by typing: ` prefdir`

Comment: do you have a `startup.m` function in your Matlab path? does this error occurs if you start Matlab with different "Starting directory"?